# Syntax to import XML to Unity properly

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have to import an XML file to Unity, but cant figure out the right syntax.

So I have created a Road Class and a RoadContainer Class as shown in this article:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

public class Road {
[XmlAttribute("name")]
public string name;
[XmlAttribute("id")]
public float id;
[XmlAttribute("junction")]
```

This is Container Class

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO; 

[XmlRoot("OpenDrive")]
public class RoadsContainer {

[XmlArray("Roads")]
[XmlArrayItem("Road")]
public List<Road> roads = new List<Road>();

public static RoadsContainer Load(string path){

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RoadsContainer));
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
 return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as RoadsContainer;
}
}
```

I want to add something like this to the class:

```
<OpenDrive>
  <Raods>
    <Road name="" ... >
      <link>
         <successor elementId="1" elementType="Road" />
      </link>
      <planview>
         <geometry attribute1 attribute2 ...>
         <line/>
         </geometry>
     </planview>
   </Road>
   <Road>
   </Road>
 </Roads>
</OpenDrive>
```

I tried to add the "link" as another class with the XmlElement of "successor" and XmlElementAttributes(not in this code, but in another), but nothing worked

```
public class link {
[XmlElement("successor")]
public float elementId;
public string elementType;
public string contactPoint; 
}
```

It would be nice if anyone could help me out with some code or a link to a good documentation for porper XML syntax in Unity c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a dedicated class for each `XmlElement` (sub-tag) that is further nested.

So something like

```
[Serializable]
public class Road 
{
     [XmlAttribute] public string name;
     [XmlAttribute] public float id;

     // ...

     [XmlElement] public Link link; 
     [XmlElement] public PlanView planview;
}

[Serializable]
public class Link {
    [XmlElement] public Successor successor;
}    

[Serializeable]
public class Successor
{
   [XmlAttribute] public string elementId;
   [XmlAttribute] public string elementType;
}

[Serializable]
public class PlanView
{
    [XmlElement] public Geometry geometry;
}

[Serializable]
public class Geometry 
{
    [XmlAttribute] public <type> Attribute1;
    [XmlAttribute] public <type> Attribute2;

    [XmlElement] public Line line;
}

[Seializable]
public class Line
{
    // etc ...
}
```

Note that you can skip the tag name definition (`XmlAttribute("xyz")`) if the tag in the XML file should be the same as the variable name. You only need it if the tag in the file does not euqal the variable name in the script.

You should also consider making all those XML classes `[Serializable]` so you can easely see and edit values in the Inspector within Unity. Makes it a lot easier to click together the initial XML data you need in a different script e.g. like

```
public class XmlManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RoadsContainer container = new RoadsContainer;
}
```

Ofcourse you should implement something for writing and reading into that script to be able to save and load the data from the editor.

And also note this is c# => They don't have to be placed within one file but you could have one script for each class if you want to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, i will try to do do it that way!